# add p5 canvas to angular component

Tags: angular, p5.js

I am building a angular component `clock.component` with `p5js`.

Full source from her:
https://github.com/avsmips/angular4-p5js-app/blob/master/src/app/analog-clock/analog-clock.component.ts

Html:

```
<div id="analog-clock-canvas"></div>
```

Ts:

```
createCanvas() {
   console.log("creating canvas");
   this.p5 = new p5(p => this.drawing(p));
}

drawing(p) {
   p.setup = () => {
   p.createCanvas(400, 400).parent("analog-clock-canvas");      
   ...
}
```

`p5` creates a canvas and adds into parent div `analog-clock-canvas` with 1 declaration. However it also add the canvas into the first compoment if multiple compoments are used.

```
<div class="flow">
  <app-clock></app-clock>
  <app-clock></app-clock>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you expand on how exactly the `drawing` function works? What is `p`?

Comment: just copy from this project: https://github.com/avsmips/angular4-p5js-app/blob/master/src/app/analog-clock/analog-clock.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `parent('analog-clock-canvas')` selects by id, and all components have the same, since you have hard coded it (I'm talking about `<div id="analog-clock-canvas"></div>`). Selecting by id, will bring the first result that matches, regardless of how many exists in the DOM.

I recommend generating a unique id in your component's `ngOnInit` and assigning it to the `div`. I like to use GUIDs. For example, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/12398336) implementation:

**`analog-clock.component.ts`**

```js
...

private containerId: string;

...

ngOnInit() {
    this.containerId = this.uuidv4();
}

...

// Taken from:
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/12398336
private uuidv4() {
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  );
}

...

private drawing = function(p: any) {
    p.setup = () => {
      p.createCanvas(400, 400).parent(this.containerId);      
      ...
```

**`analog-clock.component.html`**

```html
<div [id]=[containerId]></div>
```